# A consequence of Lipschitzianity in $[a, b]\subset\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

I have to the following statement. Let $g:[a, b]\subset\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$. So
$$
L(g, [a, b])=\frac{|g(b)-g(a)|}{|b-a|}\Longrightarrow \ g(a+t(b-a))=g(a)+t(g(b)-g(a))\ \ \text{for}\ 0\leq t\leq1,
$$
where $L(g, [a, b])$ is the Lipschitz constant of $g$ in $[a, b]$.

How can I show this? Some helps?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The hypothesis says that $|g(b)-g(a)|$ is as large as it can possibly get, given the Lipschitz constant. Draw a picture, and imagine what happens if the graph of $g$ is not a straight line between $a$ and $b$. It has to be steeper than $L$ somewhere?

**Edit:** Here is a second hint. With $a<t<b$, put $x=a+t(b-a)$ and $y=g(a)+t(g(b)-g(a))$. You want to prove that $g(x)=y$. The two inequalities $|g(x)-g(a)|<L(x-a)$ and $|g(b)-g(x)|<L(b-x)$ become four inequalities if you undo the absolute values on the left. Perhaps you can use them to prove that $g(x)\le y$ and $g(x)\ge y$?

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand your hint. What do you mean for "it has to be steeper than $L$ somewhere?" ?

Comment: By “it”, I mean the graph. Draw a broken line from $(a,g(a))$ via $(x,g(x))$ to $(b,g(b))$, where $x=a+t(b-a)$. If it is indeed broken, having a corner at $x$, then one leg must be steeper, the other less steep, than the direct line from $(a,g(a))$ to $(b,g(b))$. Once you get the geometric picture, the proof is not too hard to put together.

Comment: By referring to the second hint, I cannot understand how the two inequalities $|g(x)-g(a)|<L(x-a)$ and $|g(b)-g(x)|<L(b-x)$ prove that $g(x)\leq y$ and $g(x)\geq y$. I undo both the absolute values and by the first inequality I obtain that $g(a)+\frac{|g(b)-g(a)|}{|b-a|}(a-x)<g(x)<g(a)+\frac{|g(b)-g(a)|}{|b-a|}(x-a)$. How can I conclude?

Comment: I admit my second hint was formulated a bit clumsily. But since you accepted the answer, I assume you got it together anyhow.